# why wont my select form that is written with an while loop and has values from a database retrive the corect values and work?

Tags: php, mysql, database, input, while-loop

I have a database with information about people.

It is linked to their address.

I wanted to use php and a form to insert new people into that database.

I made the form for firstname and lastname in a form element i body, and then used php code because I wanted to make an input of select type, which would automatically update with new addresses when I added them in later.

However, I cannot get the select input to work. I put it in a while loop, and it only works when I set `<option value= 1>` or a number, but not when I set it to `$adress_id`.

Below is my code. Any help would really be appreciated, but because I am a beginner I would love to retrieve straighfoward and easy answers.

Thanks in advance!

```
<form method="post">
       Fornavn
       <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="skriv inn fornavn">
       Etternavn
       <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="skriv inn etternavn">

      <?php
$sql= "SELECT * FROM adress";
$resultat= $kobling->query($sql);

echo "<select name='adress_id'>";
while ($rad= $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
  $adress_id=$rad["adress_id"];
  $street=$rad["street"];
  $street_number=$rad["street_number"];
  $adresse= $street. " ". $street_number;
  // echo "<option value= 1> $adresse </option>";
  echo "< option value=$adress_id> $adresse </option>";

}       ?>


<input type="submit" name="leggtil" value="Legg til">
     </form>
```

Comment: Missing a `</select>` I think

Comment: yes, i did! thank you. however it did not solve my problem...

Comment: Space between `<` and `option`? Not sure if that will actually cause a problem but remove space just in case

Comment: In fact try `echo "<option value='$adress_id'>$adresse</option>";`

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem!  just one more thing.. i am pretty new to this forum, but i see now that i have retrived two downvotes. is there any thing i did wrong? anything i could improve? answers much apricated!

Comment: Not really sure why

Comment: It's a little illegible. Perhaps that's why.